# copy rich text from ie wordPad and paste in a contentEditable field

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard, clipboarddata

copying from a rich text editor, for example wordPad puts the text in the clipboard as Rich Text Format (159).

How can that be then pasted to a contentEditable div with the rich text formatting.

In a 'paste' handler, it seems that in this case `e.clipboardData.getData('text/html')` returns an empty string and `e.clipboardData.getData('text/rtf')` is not supported properly - I get an empty string in Chrome and the RTF markup in firefox, both are not helpful.

Can this be done ?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190770/detect-a-paste-event-in-a-contenteditable

Comment: Sorry I can't see how it is relevant